# Expression has changed after it was checked, getting error in testing an angular 2 component with jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting an error while testing a component that is receiving an observable from the service, I have tried to mock that behaviour in the spec but I am getting the following error: Expression has changed after it was checked, previous vale '', current value: [object Object]. Could you please help me with this. My spec file is as follows:

```
import { ManualProcessService } from '../../services/manual-process.service';
import { ManualProcessComponent } from './manual-process.component';
import { MANUALPROCESSMOCKDATA } from '../../shared/mocks/mock-manualprocessdata';
import {DataTableModule, SharedModule, DropdownModule as PrimeNgDropDownModule, CheckboxModule, InputTextModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {MenuModule} from 'primeng/components/menu/menu';
import {DropdownModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import { PopoverModule } from 'ng2-popover';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IManualProcessData} from '../../models/manual-process.model';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  async,
  TestBed,
  fakeAsync,
  tick,
} from '@angular/core/testing';

class MockManualProcessService {

  getManualProcessData(): Observable<IManualProcessData> {
      return Observable.of(MANUALPROCESSMOCKDATA);
  }
}

describe('Testing Manual Process Component', () => {

  let fixture,
  event = {
    first: 0,
    rows: 10
  }, 
  manualProcessService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ManualProcessComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ManualProcessService, useClass: MockManualProcessService }
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule, 
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DataTableModule,
        SharedModule,
        PopoverModule,
        PrimeNgDropDownModule,
        DropdownModule.forRoot(),
        CheckboxModule,
        InputTextModule,
        MenuModule
    ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManualProcessComponent);
    manualProcessService = TestBed.get(ManualProcessService);
    spyOn(manualProcessService, 'getManualProcessData').and.returnValue(Observable.of(MANUALPROCESSMOCKDATA));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('Filters should be reset', (done) => {
    fixture.componentInstance.clearFilters()
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.filterBy.length).toBe(0);
    done();
  })


  it('Should load list of manual process files', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.componentInstance.loadData(event);
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.componentInstance.filterBy.length).toBe(10);
  }));
});
```

I am new to angular 2 and unit testing. Can someone guide, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The changes should be detected every time the value is changed and your before Each will be executed before the value is assigned so hi will get the error have the

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Inside your it statements and call for every change in value.

Update 1:

```
import { ManualProcessService } from '../../services/manual-process.service';
import { ManualProcessComponent } from './manual-process.component';
import { MANUALPROCESSMOCKDATA } from '../../shared/mocks/mock-manualprocessdata';
import { IManualProcessData } from '../../models/manual-process.model';
import {
    async,
    TestBed,
    fakeAsync,
    tick,
} from '@angular/core/testing';
// used to interact with the HTML elements 
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('Testing Manual Process Component', () => {

    let fixture,
        event = {
            first: 0,
            rows: 10
        },
        manualProcessService;
    let hardCodedData = {
        ...
    };
    beforeEach(async () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            declarations: [ManualProcessComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: ManualProcessService, useValue: mockManualProcessService }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManualProcessComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        element = fixture.nativeElement;
        // analyse your component and the variables used in it and make hard values of them
        let variables;
        // Note: Never call detectChanges() inside a beforeEach
    })

    it('Filters should be reset', (done) => {
        fixture.componentInstance.clearFilters();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.filterBy.length).toBe(0);
        done();
    })

    it('Should load list of manual process files', fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.componentInstance.loadData(event);
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.filterBy.length).toBe(10);
    }));

    it('a sample case to check if the text box contains expected value aor not',()=>{
        expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.className')).nativeElement.textContent).toBe('somename');
    });
});
```

Comment: In some time pls  heading Office

Comment: Yes what is the HTML or your trying to achieve. Be clear on the logica

Comment: the problem is that, when I return an empty object in the observable, it works fine, but when I return it with the data it gives the above error

Comment: Which line. And u Should not use observables for unit testing.

Comment: return Observable.of(MANUALPROCESSMOCKDATA);  So, how could I test the component subscribing the actual observable. Can you guide me to an article doing so.

Comment: Definitely I will, reach me out at fb @ aravind2109

Comment: I have send you request @fb

Comment: I am facing similar issue @Aravind Can you have a look at my question if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879126/fixture-detectchanges-method-resulting-in-test-case-to-fail

Answer (score 10):

I was having this problem too, and changed my test to target the component's ngOnInit() method directly. So, instead of

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

in your tests, you could try

```
fixture.componentInstance.ngOnInit();
```

(or whatever lifecycle hook is the entry point for your component). That worked for me. It unblocked me from tests that were falling over even though the component itself ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me adding the following to the @Component configuration solved my problem:

```
@Component({
...
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: This also mostly works for me and is my preferred solution, but I've had places where I had to resort to calling ngOnInit instead of detectChanges where the 3rd party component I was using was not updating when I was using OnPush.

Answer (score 1):

For such errors, Please run the application(ng serve) &

check browser console if getting the same error

If so, It will be like this

```
core.mjs:6494 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.mjs:6744:1)
at bindingUpdated (core.mjs:12747:1)
at ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:14480:1)
at TableComponent_td_10_Template (template.html:98:11)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9632:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9495:1)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10646:1)
at refreshView (core.mjs:9519:1)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10692:1)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9291:1)
```

Click on **template.html**,
it'll navigate to the line from where error is coming in the template.
Accordingly check & change the data.

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after the changes below

Change your beforeEach

```
beforeEach(() => {
    ...
})
```

to

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    ...
})
```